# IK Chain twists leg

Tags: rigging

Okay, so for whatever reason, this rig of mnie keeps insisting on bending/twisting the leg sideways everytime I try to move it upwards. It's a extremelly frusrtating behaviour that I cannot figure out why it's doing it.

[image]

I've done many IK rigs in the past and i've never had this issue. Is this a bug in 2.82?

Blend:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hi. I figured out what the problem was. The local Y axis on the bone named DEF_Thigh.L was not pointing directly in line with the next bone in the chain, named DEF_Knee.L. It was off slightly, pointing roughly in the direction of the worldspace origin, instead of straight down the bone chain. By going into edit mode, and rotating DEF_Thigh.L slightly, I was able to get the IK for the leg to move vertically without the side-to-side weirdness. While it didn't prove important in this case, I discovered that the bone roll on several joints were also not zeroed out when the armature is in its rest pose, and it is probably a good practice to make sure that they are. I wanted to thank you for your question because I learned some things by playing with your file.

Comment: Okay, that is rather embarassing. I was certain that the rolls were zero on this. And I guess I should've paid more attention to the thigh's rotation. After five years of using Blender and using creating rigs, I still make the rookie mistakes....

I'm glad that it atleast helped you in some way. :)